# Why does my executable not run from a bash script called through udev?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, udev, executable

I have an executable compiled from my code. I am trying to run this executable when I insert a serial device into my Raspberry Pi Zero W using `udev`. However, for some reason the executable will not run, I have looked with `top` and there is no sign of the process.

Here my udev rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-serial-usb.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", KERNEL=="1-1.3", ATTR{idProduct}=="7523", ATTR{idVendor}=="1a86", RUN="/bin/bash /home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/run.sh"
```

And here is the bash script in `/home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/bin/blackbox &
```

The bash script definitely runs because I have used commands like `mkdir` and `touch` from the script to test that it is actually being run, and they each work correctly. So why is my executable different?

Let me clarify that by not working, I mean that the executable does not appear to be running with `top`.

Comment: Does it work better if you run the executable directly from the udev rule? Unless there is more to your script you are not showing us, that is just adding a pointless layer of complexity. What happens if you just have `RUN="/home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/bin/blackbox"` in the `udev` rule? Also, `top` only shows the top processes by whatever you are sorting with, better to test with `pgrep blackbox` or `ps aux | grep blackbox`.

Comment: Is the executable you're running interacting with a graphical user interface (opening windows etc.)?

Comment: @Kusalananda No, it all runs through a CLI.

Comment: @terdon Yeah, I've tried before running it directly from the udev rule. All with the same outcome. The process either isn't running at all, or its runs very briefly before terminating.

Comment: Are you not doing any error checking, debugging output, or logging from your own code?

Comment: OK, so it's erroring out. Change your script so that it runs `/home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/bin/blackbox 2>/tmp/blackbox.log  1>&2` and then check the file `/tmp/blackbox.log` for errors.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, my program logs output to a log file inside a directory called 'logs'. This directory is supposed to be created during runtime, but its not. If I run the bash script from the command line without udev it works just fine.

Comment: So there's an issue (permissions, wrong working directory, etc.) creating the directory that you don't catch, or another error occurs before the directory is created that aborts the code, either in your code or in the run-time system of whatever language framework you're using.

Comment: Thanks @terdon that's helped me discover the error. Could you explain what that does?

Comment: It just redirects the script's standard error and standard output to a file so you can check. See [How to redirect stderr to a file](https://askubuntu.com/a/625230)

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question, turns out there was an error when reading my configuration file. I am using a JSON file to read in a set of configurations and because `udev` runs items from the root directory, it could not find this file.

So all I had to change in my bash script to get around this was inserting a change directory to the path of the configuration file.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/guy/blackbox-cpp/
bin/blackbox
```

Thanks to @terdon who helped me to discover the error.

Comment: You probably want `./bin/blackbox` there, even if you are on a system that adds `.` to the PATH, it is more portable and cleaner to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

`top` displays the top CPU users (default). The list is not the list of all processes running. It is possible that your application uses very little CPU and therefore, it might not be in the top.

To be sure that the process does not run, try

```
ps -ef | grep blackbox
```

You may also change the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > /tmp/blackbox.sh.pid
/home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/bin/blackbox
```

and do a `pstree -an xxxxx` where xxxxx is the PID in your PID file.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. I put that in my bash script and I got a PID output in the /tmp/blackbox.sh.pid file. However, when I used pstree, there was no further output. So that suggests to me that the process starts but immediately closes?

Comment: I missed the `&` add the end of the command. Remove that `&`.

Comment: Removed the &, still no output.

Comment: Then your `/home/blackbox/blackbox-cpp/bin/blackbox` exists directly.  Without knowing anything about your `blackbox`, it is very hard to make any suggestions. If there are any logging or debug options,enable them all. They might give some clue on what's going wrong. Also, redirect the STDOUT and STDERR of yoour cpp-version to some files.

Answer (score 0):

See `man 7 udev`:

> Starting daemons or other long-running processes is not allowed; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed after the event handling has finished.

If you want to run background process in udev rule create systemd service and start it with `systemctl start <your_service>`.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, hence why I am running from a bash script. Will that not get around this?

Comment: @GuyChamberlain-Webber added to answer.

Comment: @GuyChamberlain-Webber No. Udev run programs in separate namespace and terminate all child processes spawned by program.